# how to show stdout outputs of two programs side by side

Tags: text-formatting

`paste` can show the contents of two files side by side.

How can I show the stdout outputs of two programs side by side? Can it be done by pipe?

Answer (score 7):

You can use process substitution, something like `paste <(cmd1) <(cmd2)`.