# fixing or finding an alternative to bad 'paste <(jcal) <(ccal)' output

Tags: shell-script, text-formatting

*(I don't have a high enough reputation to comment my question into: [how to show stdout outputs of two programs side by side](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/286109/how-to-show-stdout-outputs-of-two-programs-side-by-side) )*

I've tried `paste <(jcal) <(ccal)`
but the output is messed up.

`jcal; ccal;` gives the correct output, just not side by side.

```
      Tir 1402      
Sh Ye Do Se Ch Pa Jo
                1  2
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14 15 16
17 18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29 30
31 

       July 2023       
 Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa   
                    1   
  2  3  4< 5> 6  7  8   
  9 10 11 12 13 14 15   
 16 17 18 19 20 21 22   
 23 24 25 26 27 28 29   
 30 31
```

*The real output has colors and the `jcal` date is colored differently*

But with `paste <(jcal) <(ccal)`, the colors are removed and the two outputs become intermingled.

```
      Tir 1402          
Sh Ye Do Se Ch Pa Jo           July 2023       
                1  2     Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa   
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9                        1   
10 11 12 13 14 15 16      2  3  4< 5> 6  7  8   
17 18 19 20 21 22 23      9 10 11 12 13 14 15   
24 25 26 27 28 29 30     16 17 18 19 20 21 22   
31                       23 24 25 26 27 28 29   
     30 31
```

Is there a better way to display `jcal` and `ccal` outputs beside one another?

Like this, but with the appropriate colors:

```
      Tir 1402                 July 2023       
Sh Ye Do Se Ch Pa Jo     Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa   
                1  2                        1   
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9      2  3  4< 5> 6  7  8   
10 11 12 13 14 15 16      9 10 11 12 13 14 15   
17 18 19 20 21 22 23     16 17 18 19 20 21 22   
24 25 26 27 28 29 30     23 24 25 26 27 28 29   
31                       30 31
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you just need to remove the first line of the output of `ccal`:

```
$ paste <(jcal) <(ccal|tail -n+2)
      Tir 1402                 July 2023
Sh Ye Do Se Ch Pa Jo     Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
                1  2                     1  2
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9      3  4< 5> 6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14 15 16     10 11 12 13 14 15 16
17 18 19 20 21 22 23     17 18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29 30     24 25 26 27 28 29 30
31                       31
```

Looks like `ccal` only outputs in color when stdout goes to a tty (even with an explicit `--use-color`) and also doesn't restore color to default at the end of each line (causing nasty artefacts on some terminals). You can work around both with something like:

```
paste <(jcal) <(socat -u exec:ccal,pty exec:'tail -n+2') |
  sed $'s/$/\e[m/'
```

Where `socat` uses a pseudo-terminal device (pty) to transfer data between `ccal` and `tail` instead of a pipe and `sed` adds the `<ESC>[m` SGR0 escape sequence at the end of each line to reset graphic rendering attributes to the default.

[image: screenshot of the above]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it doesn't have all the same colors, but at least it's readable and I'm happy enough with that.

This is what worked:

`paste <(ccal) <(printf '\n \t' && jcal)`

Output:

```
    
       July 2023                  Tir 1402      
 Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa       Sh Ye Do Se Ch Pa Jo
                    1                       1  2
  2  3  4< 5> 6  7  8        3  4  5  6  7  8  9
  9 10 11 12 13 14 15       10 11 12 13 14 15 16
 16 17 18 19 20 21 22       17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 23 24 25 26 27 28 29       24 25 26 27 28 29 30
 30 31                      31
```

**Update**: If you want to display the twilights and sunrise and sunset in between them, you can use `sunwait` and this script (with the knowledge gained from Stéphane Chazelas's excellent solution above):

```
paste <(jcal) <(printf '\n' && sunwait list 1 astronomical 27.96382229N 86.91248325E && sunwait list 1 nautical 27.96382229N 86.91248325E && sunwait list 1 civil 27.96382229N 86.91248325E && sunwait list 1 daylight 27.96382229N 86.91248325E && printf '            \n \t \n \t \n \t \n \t \n \t') <(printf '\t' && socat -u exec:ccal,pty exec:'tail -n+2') |   sed $'s/$/\e[m/'
```

[image: Output:]

Just edit the GPS coordinates.

It works in both the console and graphical terminals.

`sunwait report 27.000N 73.9385723W`  will give you a report that includes the twilights as well as solar noon, if you're interested.

```
Current Date and Time: 05-Jul-2023 13:33 EDT


Target Information ...

                   Location:  27.000000N, 286.061428E
                       Date: 04-Jul-2023
                   Timezone: EDT
   Sun directly north/south: 13:00
             Twilight angle: -0.83 degrees (daylight)
          Day with twilight: 06:04 to 19:55
                      It is: Day (or twilight)

General Information (no offset) ...

 Times ...         Daylight: 06:04 to 19:55
        with Civil twilight: 05:39 to 20:20
     with Nautical twilight: 05:08 to 20:51
 with Astronomical twilight: 04:34 to 21:25

 Duration ...    Day length: 13:50 hours
        with civil twilight: 14:40 hours
     with nautical twilight: 15:43 hours
 with astronomical twilight: 16:50 hours
```

Thanks again to Stéphane Chazelas for the awesome solution above and especially for figuring out the color part!